# div with height 100% is not expanding to match parent div

Tags: css

I am new to CSS/JS so this may be a simple question, but I've struggled with this for a few hours (trying different combinations of CSS classes, etc.)

I've got the following configuration currently (using Tailwind CSS):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main relative pb-10 min-h-screen">
<!-- Takes entire height of screen -->
  <div class="p-3 min-h-full">
  <!-- Has minimal ht (not matching parent)  -->
    <div class="h-full">
      <div class="h-full">
        <textarea class="resize-none border-rounded-md min-w-full h-full">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the textarea (and parent divs) to match the parent div and take up full height. I've also tried adding CSS to make the HTML have max-height, but it did nothing. This is code from a react tutorial with some of my own modifications. Every div after the first, parent div has minimal height, so the issue seems to be between the first and second divs.

```
/* Tailwind CSS */
.min-h-screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.min-h-full {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I will try to give a detailed answer to your question after the holidays.

Answer (score 0):

The `height: 100%` only does what you want it to do if the parent element's height is explicitly set, such as `height: 400px`. I think this is because the viewport height can change as the browser is resized, and it would have to do a lot of recalculation to make that work. And if they changed it now that computers are more powerful, it'd probably break a bunch of websites, so we're stuck with it.

The modern CSS way to fill the height of the parent is to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score -2):

First div has a pair of quotes missing `<div class = "relative pb-10 min-h-screen">`. Not sure is what is causing the issue.

Comment: the typos have nothing to do with how height and min-height work with percentages.

Comment: try h-screen for the first div